# ActionBarSherlock Tab - Slide

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, slide

I am using the ActionBarSherlock by Jake Wharton; and in one of my activities, I use the Tab Navigation.
And, I've a ViewFlipper to manage some views.

But, I want that the user would be able to slide between the tabs.

It's works, safe if in the showed view (so, the showed viewFlipper's child) there is another view.

Example :

```
<LinearLayout>
     <ViewFlipper>
          <LinearLayout> //First View

          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout> //Second View

               <TextView/>

          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout> //Third View

          </LinearLayout>
     </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I'm in the first view (or the third), the sliding works fine; but not in the second.

1. **Why ?**
2. **How to fix that ? Should I set the Touch Listener to all "subviews" ?**

*PS:* I set the listener to the (root) LinearLayout containing the viewFlipper.

Comment: Have you considered using a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` instead of the `ViewFlipper`?

Answer (score 0):

I understood like 40% of your question. Please proofread your question before you summit it. I’m really confused about a couple of things.  #1 Are u using Views or Fragments? If you are using tabs, u should be using fragments!  #2 Are you switching between the fragments via a ViewFlipper, Swiping/ Horizontal Paging, by using the Tabs, or all 3 simultaneously.

In response to your second question, if you are using ViewFlipper, you need to implement OnClickListener and when a user clicks on the Flipper, the app will go into the method onClick.  If u implement View.OnTouchListener, the app will go into the method onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event). Notice the parameters for onTouch. You need a MotionEvent. ViewFlipper is best for short taps. MotionEvent is best for swipes.

In order to activity the ViewFlipper, you need:

1) `flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);`
2) `flippy.setOnClickListener(this);   //This is to make the ViewFlipper respond to clicks.`
3) `implements OnClickListener  //This goes on top of your class (after “extends”).`
4) Then when a user actually clicks on the ViewFlipper, the program will go to the method:

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {flippy.showNext();}
```

In response to your first question. I’m guessing your question is this:
1) Why can’t I use ViewFlipper to slide between more than 2 items?
This is how. Here is sample code for a class called Flippering.java:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

    public class Flippering extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
        ViewFlipper flippy;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.h_swipe_neg_one);
            flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
            flippy.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flippy.showNext();
        }

    }
```

Here is the corresponding XML document:

```
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="Clicked">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/autumn_leaves" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/azul" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/big_mountain" >
        </ImageView>
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that `android:src="@drawable/big_mountain"` refers to images that I have in my res/drawable-hdpi folder. Also, instead of `<ImageView>`, you can use a `<TextView>`. So for example:

```
<ViewFlipper>
   <TextView></TextView>
   <TextView></TextView>
   <TextView></TextView>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Additionally, I highly doubt your problem has anything to do with ActionBarSherlock.